# Understanding the faulting of Transformables in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nsvaluetransformer

I have the problem in my app, that deleting a lot of data out of my Database takes very long. So I started debugging and found out, that the value-transformers are the problem!

To see the problem I created a project that isolates the problem...

I have the following:

```
+-----------+     +-----------+
| Entity  A |     | Entity  B |
+-----------+     +-----------+
|           |     | property  |
| b         | 1:1 | a         |
+-----------+     +-----------+
```

So `Entity A` has a 1:1 relation to `Entity B`. And `Entitiy B` has a property called `property` which is Transformable and has a ValueTransformer. The delete rule of A to B is nullify.

Now I create one instance of A and B, link them and write something into property. Save the context and everything works as expected.

Now I want to delete all object of `Entity A`. I create a fetch request, and delete all entities. In my sample I do that like so:

```
context.perform {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<EntityA>(entityName: "EntityA")
    guard let allEntities = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) else { return }

    for entity in allEntities {
        context.delete(entity)
    }
    try? context.save()
}
```

And now when that save happens, the value transformers `reverseTransformedValue` is called. And I don't understand WHY?!? Cause I don't access that property... I don't set or get it...

Would be cool if somebody could shed some light for me.

I also have my sample project available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/651dmyughosr90p/ValueTransformerIssue-Sample.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting and somewhat surprising result, but I think it's Core Data operating normally. A couple of background details on Core Data:

- When an object is read, it's normally a "fault". Property values aren't immediately loaded unless you configure your fetch request to require loading.
- When the fault object "fires", **all** property values are loaded. This happens automatically when you access any property value, so if you look up one property, all property values are loaded.
- In order to change the value on a property, Core Data is going to load the property values.

In your case what appears to be happening is:

- You fetch instances of `EntityA`.
- You delete those instances.
- Since you're using "nullify" as the delete rule, deleting an `EntityA` means that Core Data needs to modify the corresponding `EntityB` by setting its value for `a` to nil.
- Internally Core Data needs to load the `EntityB` instance. Since it's modifying one of the properties, it first loads all of the properties. At this point your value transformer executes even though it isn't really needed here.

If your value transformers are hurting performance, some things you might try to fix that include:

- Move this property to a separate entity that's related to `EntityB`. Relationships faults don't fire when property faults do, so the nullify rule wouldn't load instances of this new entity.
- Although `NSBatchDeleteRequest` will not honor delete rules (so "nullify" won't be applied), you might be able to combine one with an `NSBatchUpdateRequest` to fix the relationship. Something like, do a batch delete for `EntityA` instances followed by a batch update to set the relationship to nil on affected `EntityB` instances.

Or of course, maybe your value transformer can be optimized so that it's less of a problem?

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Hello Tom, nice reading from you again :)
I guess you are right, that the nilling out of the relation is the problem.
In my real app (not just this sample here) I already have a separate entity that contains the Value-Transformable data on it. Just the data and nothing else because of the fact that faulting loads everything. And the other problem is that this data simply is big. It's GPS data of activities you record.
I guess the best solution would be to write those to a file and just reference them from core data i guess?!?
I also looked at the `NSBatchUpdateRequest` but since I have...

Comment: ... quite some relations that would be too much pain to get right... I guess I'll just have to find a better way to store my data since having that much binary in sql isn't a good idea anyway...
I'll wait a bit more to accept you answer just in case a miracle happens and somebody has a super easy solution... but thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Comment: @Tom I thought NSBatchDeleteRequest does honour delete rules - just not custom validation?

Comment: @pbasdf I don't think so but I could be mistaken.